# Passing instance variable between managed beans

Tags: jsf

I am trying to get the **UserBeans** instance variables from **LoginBean** class. I want to use instance variable of **Userbean** into **LoginBean** class. Someone helps me.

1. Here, **UserBean.java** class :

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class UserBean {

       private String name;

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }
   }
   ```
2. And, Here's **LoginBean.java** class :

   ```
   public class LoginBean {

       public String login_check() {
           if(name.equals("mahbub")){
               return "success";
             }else
                return "fail";
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
public class LoginBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{userBean}")
    private UserBean userBean;

    public String login_check() {
        if(userBean.getName().equals("mahbub")){
            return "success";
          }else
             return "fail";
    }
}
```

But you should rethink your design pattern

Answer (score 0):

Inject your `UserBean` class into `LoginBean` class and generate its getter and setter. So, your code should look like this.

```
public class LoginBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{userBean}")
    private UserBean userBean;

    public String login_check() {
        if(name.equals("mahbub")) {
            return "success";
          } else {
             return "fail";
          }
    }

    // userBean getter and setter here
}
```

Hope this would work for you. Cheers!